# MATLAB's worskpace it's not showing the variable's names

Tags: matlab, workspace

I recently configured my layout to default mode, but now I'm not seeing the name of my variables in the worskpace.

[image: workspace]

how can I solve this?

Comment: the question was too trivial, so earned down vote?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at your picture it seems the `Name` column has been shrunk so that the name of the variable can not be displayed (notice the `...` in the red circle in the figure below).

[image]

You can try enlarging it by left clicking with the mouse on the column separator and dragging it to the right. This should enlarge the `Name` column an allow seeing the varaibles' name as per in the following picture.

[image]

Hope this helps.

Qapla'